# Get last distinct value from 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like some help with this code. I'm trying to select the last chat message im MySQL. This is my table:

| id | id_user_to | id_user_from | message | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | Hi | 1633345082 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | Hello | 1633345083 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | Another | 1633345088 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | Another2 | 1633345088 |

If I were to select the last message of user 1 I would get the second line, as it has the most recent timestamp. How can I do? I tried this code but I don't know how to adapt it to my context as I have to check that the user is taken once either in the `from_user_id` or `to_user_id` column, always with the most recent timestamp.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [tableName] 
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT MAX(id)
  FROM [tableName]
  GROUP BY code
)
```

Comment: If you're using Mysql 8, `row_number` can do this for you easily.

Comment: Do you want the latest message *from* the user or *from or to*? If the latter then id 2,3 & 4 qualify, if the former then only 2 & 4. Which should it be?

Comment: 2, 3 and 4......

Comment: In which case you have an answer - but you've also contradicted what you posted in the comments below.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the last message sent or received by a specific user :

```
select * from [tableName] 
where id_user_to = 1 or id_user_from = 1
order by timestamp desc limit 1
```

ok for your second question:

```
select * from (
select *, row_number() over (partition by user1,user2 order by timestamp desc) rn 
from (
   select id ,id_user_to user1,id_user_from user2,message,timestamp
   from table where id_user_to =1
   union all
   select id ,id_user_from, id_user_to,message,timestamp
   from table  where id_user_from =1
) t ) t where rn = 1
```

and If you remove conditions on userids inside sub queries , you get the latest messages for all the user ids

Comment: Thanks, but I would need to select all the latest messages that user 1 exchanges with any other user. I changed the question, I would like to select lines 2 and 4 and so on. Comparing where user 1 is and choosing the most recent timestamp

Comment: @Gae see updated answer